# Listview not entirely rendered at animation completion

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

When an animation plays on a ListView which is placed on top of a VideoView in a RelativeLayout (this happens when the ListView is placed above some other view types as well, but not for example, ImageView), I get a bad result. The ListView is not rendered entirely. If I press the home button and re-enter the app, the ListView is rendered correctly. See the two screenshots here, before and after:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrfR3.jpg

I have created as simple a test application as I could, find the project/source here:

http://www.whatsbeef.net/wabz/AnimationTest.tar.gz

Or see the paste of code here: http://gist.github.com/2934018

Note: After removing the rotationY objectAnimation, the ListView is displayed correctly. I do not know what I'm doing wrong here, or if this is an Android bug, or what. I get the same behaviour on a device and x86 emulator (4.0.3). Any ideas?

Comment: I have submitted a bug for this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33424